# Webkit canvas drawImage() and canvas not-integer scale factor bug?

Tags: canvas, webkit, drawimage

I've got a problem with canvas context drawImage() method if an image is drawn on a canvas that already has not-integer scale factor. It seems that such images are clipped in a weird way (sometimes the most right part of an image is clipped, sometimes the most bottom side, sometimes both). This problem appears at least in Google Chrome 6 (at least stable), Chromium 6, perhaps even latest (dev-)builds too, and even Safari 5. Firefox has not this bug. Obviously, it's a Webkit problem if I'm not wrong. Let's look at the following code (provided entire code for a demo):

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    canvas {
      border: solid 1px black;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">    
    window.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var increase = document.getElementById("increase");
      var decrease = document.getElementById("decrease");
      var scale = document.getElementById("scale");
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var image = new Image();
      image.src = "image-3x5.png";
      var scaleX = 1;
      var scaleY = 1;
      var repaint = function() {
        scale.innerHTML = scaleX + "; " + scaleY;
        context.fillStyle = "#FFF";
        context.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 750);
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 3, 5);
      };
      var scaleXF = 1.2; // change both to 2 and it will be fixed
      var scaleYF = 1.2;
      decrease.onclick = function() {
        scaleX /= scaleXF;
        scaleY /= scaleYF;
        context.scale(1 / scaleXF, 1 / scaleYF);
        repaint();
      };
      increase.onclick = function() {
        scaleX *= scaleXF;
        scaleY *= scaleYF;
        context.scale(scaleXF, scaleYF);
        repaint();
      };
      repaint();
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <span id="scale"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="750"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div>    
    <input id="decrease" type="button" value="decrease" />    
    <input id="increase" type="button" value="increase" />    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So is it a real bug? Or are there any workarounds?

Thanks in advance.

UPD:

Let's consider we have the following BASE64-encoded 3x5 image:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAAFCAYAAACAcVaiAAAAEklEQVR42mP4z8DwH4YZyOAAAMufHeNmMS0JAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

Comment: can you give us the image as a data:image/png;base64,?

Comment: @Simon Sarris: I'm not sure if it's a well-formed base64, because I'm late and very hurry at the moment. Hope I'm not wrong. See the update please.

Comment: I am definitely reproducing the problem you're seeing (with my own image, too)

Comment: Still not fixed but in progress: code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=61198#c3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, it's a bug.

The difference between

```
context.setTransform(1*55.206143891243606, 0, 0, 1*55.206143891243606, 0, 0);
```

and

```
context.setTransform(1*55, 0, 0, 1*55, 0, 0);
```

Is massive. But only when drawing images. When filling a rectangle it works correctly.

I did a bit of testing and made this page to illustrate. The top two are with drawImage and a scale factor of 55 and 55.206143891243606. They clearly look very different.

Below are two more canvases with the same respective scale factors and a fillRect command. They look fine.

http://simonsarris.com/misc/badscale.html

This should be reported to the chromium issue tracker. Let me know if you want to do it, otherwise I will do it.

Good catch, by the way :D

Comment: @Simon: Hi again. Honestly, I have never posted any bug to any public software issue tracker, so it seems I have done #61198 in some wrong way. The bug still remains unconfirmed. Perhaps I got a wrong issue tracker (perhaps there is some special Webkit issue tracker), or should I promote #61198 there? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You did the right thing. It takes a looooong time for a lot of bugs to get responded to, they're very busy. In a few days there may be an update saying "cc'ing the people who know about Canvas." Then it could be weeks or months more before they get to a solution. All you can do now is wait :)

Comment: Best answer for paying attention for the problem and keeping interest for it. Thanks. :)

Comment: Hi again. Sorry for disturbing. At the bug tracker you wrote that the bug is fixed. My sample at http://andem.freehostia.com/webkit-scaled-image-on-canvas-bug/ have to show a strict square. Chromium (Webkit in general) fails again. Check nearest scale factors like 18.48842588950363 and 22.186111067404358 - the square does not change but... it more like shrinking... I tested it again in Chromium 67161 under WinXP/32 and Win7/64 with GPU acceleration turned on. Fails in both cases... :( Are you really sure they have fixed the bug?

Comment: Thats strange... It works in 9.0.587.0 dev if you go to the page about:flags and turn on GPU acceleration for me.